# Azure data factory data flow : expression input is a columnname

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to build a data flow in a data factory , which it will take the variable into to aggregation expression sum , avg ....

however I found it will need to see the actual column name , otherwise it will have error like in the following

[image]

$columnname is a parameter of the dataflow ...

any idea for this ?

add new screen

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The data flow parameter should be integer type to be used in aggregate functions like [sum()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#sum) and [avg()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#avg). They only accept numeric values/columns.

As shown below, I have created 2 **Data flow** parameters, one **integer** type (column), and one **string** type (column1).

[image]

When I used these parameters in `aggregate` transformation, for **sum** and **avg**, it only accepts an integer parameter and errors out when a string parameter is used.

[image]

**Update:**

Convert the string variable to integer and use aggregate function SUM/AVG

`sum(toInteger($columnname))`

[image]

Comment: hi. thanks . but actually what I should pass to variable $column is a column name , which is a string , of coz the values in that column is integer.

Comment: anyone has any idea for this ?

Comment: Hi, Can you try converting the parameter to integer first and then use SUM/AVG? Updated my answer with details.

Comment: thanks and let me try , although I have tried that before . so it works for you?

Comment: yes, it did not give any errors to me.

Comment: I have got no error , but in preview it's null in that step .

Comment: anyone has comment

Comment: anyone has any idea ?

Comment: Hi, Can you please provide a snip of how you are passing column values to parameter?

Comment: Also, can you check what is the current value is been shown in the parameter?

Comment: I pass the column variable in during the debug setting.

Comment: anyone has any idea ?